# Insert sum of group into new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple `DataFrame`:

```
gov dis value1  value2
a   a_1 8   8
a   a_2 7   18
a   a_3 3   2
a   a_4 12  12
b   b_1 4   11
b   b_2 16  9
b   b_3 17  12
b   b_4 7   9
b   b_5 15  11
b   b_6 13  16
```

I can create a sum of all values in `value1` easily.

```
per_t['sum_v1'] = sum(per_t['value1'])
```

Producing:

```
    gov dis value1  value2  sum_v1
0   a   a_1 8   8   102
1   a   a_2 7   18  102
2   a   a_3 3   2   102
3   a   a_4 12  12  102
4   b   b_1 4   11  102
5   b   b_2 16  9   102
6   b   b_3 17  12  102
7   b   b_4 7   9   102
8   b   b_5 15  11  102
9   b   b_6 13  16  102
```

Can this be altered to calculate sum per say `gov`? I have unsuccessfully tried `groupby` and `agg` functions. If I try:

```
per_t['sum_gov'] = per_t.groupby('gov')['value1'].sum()
```

The table reads as:

```
gov dis value1  value2  sum_v1  sum_gov
0   a   a_1 8   8   102 NaN
1   a   a_2 7   18  102 NaN
2   a   a_3 3   2   102 NaN
3   a   a_4 12  12  102 NaN
4   b   b_1 4   11  102 NaN
5   b   b_2 16  9   102 NaN
6   b   b_3 17  12  102 NaN
7   b   b_4 7   9   102 NaN
8   b   b_5 15  11  102 NaN
9   b   b_6 13  16  102 NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

```
df['sum_gov'] = df.groupby('gov')['value1'].transform(sum)
```

See [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

> The transform method returns an object that is indexed the same (same size) as the one being grouped. Thus, the passed transform function should return a result that is the same size as the group chunk.

Comment: Tried this and I get the same problem of NaN. Have updated question

Comment: Updated answer, needed to use `transform` to get back object with same index.

Comment: This may well solve the problem, but please also provide an explanation. Many new users come to SO and explanation with your code helps them to learn how to adapt the code to solve their problem. In particular, I suspect your comment should be part of the answer.